# node.js handelbars Error: Missing helper: "compare"

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

when I run this code to comparing value if it bigger than one i get this error

```
{{#compare pageCount ">" 1 }}
  <ul class="pagination"><­/ul>
    {{#compare currentPage ">" 1 }}

       <li><a href="/?page=1"> &laquo;</a></li>
    {{/compare}}

{{/compare}}
```

i installed handelbars with node.js and i tested it but i get this error always when i use compare hash ?

> ```
> Error: Missing helper: "compare"
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/helpers/helper-missing.js:19:13)
>     at Object.eval (eval at createFunctionContext (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js:254:23),
> ```
>
> :8:91)
>           at main (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:175:32)
>           at ret (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:178:12)
>           at ret (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:525:21)
>           at ExpressHandlebars._renderTemplate (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:247:12)
>           at ExpressHandlebars. (/opt/lampp/htdocs/x/chessMult/regtest/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:173:21)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make a custom helper with `Handlebars.registerHelper` you can check the full [documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to know how to register a custom helper to be able to use it in the template.